# Can an app that runs on iPad be forced to be displayed in iPhone's resolution or aspect ratio?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, applications

The example is Pokemon Go: when it is running on the iPad Pro, almost everything is fine, except you cannot see part of the upper screen and part of the lower screen.

As a result, in a gym battle, when your move is super effective or not very effective, the message at the top of the screen cannot be seen. And when you try to catch a Raid boss, the number of Premier balls remaining at the bottom of the screen cannot be seen either. (unlike iPhone).

So can you force the app to run on the iPad Pro like it is an iPhone app (or use the iPhone's screen aspect ratio -- long screen size instead of 4:3)?

(The app is published as an iPhone / iPad universal app, and all it takes is one click for the developer to publish it as an iPhone only app, and it will be running as an iPhone app on the iPad and *everything* will be visible on screen. The fact that the developer chose to publish it not as iPhone only app but with some elements not visible on screen on the iPad, is really a bad decision and therefore the user really should be allowed to choose to use it as an iPhone app on the iPad).

Comment: It depends on the size of the iPad Pro. Most "iPad friendly apps support 9" inch iPads. Which until the iPad Pro Models were the common iPad sizes.

Answer (score 5):

**No you cannot**

When the developer creates the app he/she specified the screen aspect ratio in the development software. There is no way to change the aspect ration to fit your iPad Pro.

You could recommended to the developer company to create a iPad Pro version of the app that had the proper aspect ratio for your iPad Pro.

Comment: For the fact that it can be also an iPhone app, then you are supposed to be able to show it on the iPad as an iPhone app. In this case it is also an iPad app but badly laid out, so that’s why iOS really has a reason for a user to choose to show it as an iPhone app

Comment: It depends on the size of the iPad Pro. Most "iPad friendly apps support 9" inch iPads. Which until the iPad Pro Models were the common iPad sizes.

Comment: You do know that given such high resolution of the iPad and iPad Pro, it can emulate the size of an iPhone screen very well. So, the iPad simply showed the iPhone's long screen and act like it is an iPhone. This is true for any app that is "for iPhone" and then you run it on iPad. So the major defects that some part of the screen is not showing on iPad, can be fixed by two methods (1) Niantic publishes it as iPhone only app, or (2) iOS allows iPad to show it in iPhone mode even if the app supports both iPhone and iPad mode. Either way, problem solved. But neither Niantic or iOS is doing it